# Sorting dictionary in django model using json field

Tags: python, django

I am trying to store a dictionary in my Django project as a model. The model is present but it wont update the values. any ideas?

**model.py:**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
jsonM = JSONField()
Main.py:
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print("this is my model")
MyModel.objects.all().update(jsonM=myList)
```

When i do:

```
print(MyModel.objects.all())
print(type(MyModel.objects.all()))
```

I get the following:

```
<QuerySet []>
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
newObject = MyModel(jsonM = mylist)
newObject.save()
```

Comment: Thanks woks perfectly